# Preserving Structs without Dynamic Allocation

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, malloc

I've been battling with this problem for a few hours.

I have a doubly linked list implementation that does not require dynamic memory allocation.

Here's the insertion method. It inserts `elem` right before `before`. The `struct list` has two members, `struct list_elem *next` and `struct list_elem *prev`. `list_elem` is a struct that holds some data. Please note that this list implementation is correct. The problem is with the way I am using it. Please read on.

```
void list_insert(struct list_elem *before, struct list_elem *elem) {
    /* "before" has to be an interior node or tail node to be able to insert "before" it */
    assert (is_interior(before) || is_tail(before));
    assert (elem != NULL);
    elem->prev = before->prev;
    elem->next = before;
    before->prev->next = elem;
    before-> = elem;
}
```

The way this list is initialized is as follows:

```
void list_init(struct list *list) {
    assert(list != NULL);
    list->head.prev = NULL;
    list->head.next = &list->tail;
    list->tail.prev = &list->head;
    list->tail.next = NULL;
}
```

My main class does the following:

```
struct list some_list;
static struct list_elem head;
some_list.head = head;
static struct list_elem tail;
some_list.tail = tail.
list_init(&some_list);
```

This basically creates two static `list_elem` `structs`, `head` and `tail`. And passes it into the initialization function which will wire them up together.

Now to create an element, I do the following - **here's what I am doing wrong**

```
struct list_elem element_struct;
/* Initialize element_struct members here */
struct list_elem *data = &element_struct;
list_insert( list_begin(some_list), data);
```

Now this works to insert one item. Since `some_list.head` will point to `data` which will point to `some_list.tail`. My problem is that I do this in a loop. So, as any list does, it will enter multiple data in there. I either get a `segfault` or some other error saying my element is not an interior or tail node (due to `assert`) since in each loop iteration, the data struct, `element_struct` will be reinitialized. (`list_elem` holds pointers to each other).

So my question is, how would I preserve the nodes that have been inserted? The list is not supposed to use any dynamic allocation itself. In that case, would I dynamically allocate my `list_elem` structs, and pass a dynamically allocated element into the list?

If so, how can I dynamically allocate a struct?

Comment: Each list_elem wants its own memory; yet, as you have observed, your code reserves memory for only one list_elem.  You must reserve memory for several list_elems.  Whether you reserve this memory on the stack or on the heap is up to you.  If on the stack, then you should probably reserve an array of list_elems, and pass a different one of these as elem to list_insert() each time you call list_insert().  Of curiosity, why will you not dynamically allocate memory?  Is yours an embedded application with no memory manager available?

Comment: or is this just the constraint in a homework?

Comment: I am working on a project. No constraints - I can do whatever. I was given this list to use (I definitely do not want to waste my time writing my own list). Regarding dynamic allocation, I can dynamically allocate data on my own. Its just that the list does not. After research, I just realized that I **have** to dynamically allocate the data. I have one problem, however. This `list` takes `list_elem` as nodes. To make a list of any struct, I just put `list_elem` as a member of that struct. I have the struct `job` of which `list_elem` is a member of, I am now having problems `free`ing list_elem

Comment: I tried: `free(&j->elem)` then `free(j)`. The program segfaults at `free(&j->elem). Why is that? `struct job` has `list_elem elem` as a member and `j` is a pointer that points to a `struct job`.

Comment: @Nayefc:  Fair enough.  It seems that you have answered your own question.  You are right:  dynamic allocation is the normal way to do what you suggest.  If you are still having problems freeing a list_elem, you can post that code here when you're ready.

Comment: Of what type is j?  Is j an int?  You must free(p), where p is of type "list_elem *".

Comment: `j` is of type `struct job`. `struct job` contains `struct list_elem` as a member. I would have to malloc both and free both, am I right? Freeing job using `j->elem` segfaults however.

Comment: I see your comments here.  @OliCharlesworth is leading you the right way, though.  We can continue the discussion in his answer thread below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dynamically-allocate a struct instance, it's as simple as `MyStruct *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));`, and then an associated `free(p);` at some point.

Comment: Yep. I got that. However, I have a struct within a struct, so: `struct job { ...members...; struct list_elem elem};`  Now I malloced both job and list_elem. To free job, I just call free on its pointers. But calling a free on `job->elem` segfaults. Do I need to malloc/free the embedded struct? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Is one job to own one list_elem, or to own an entire list of list_elems?

Comment: @Nayefc: If the "inner" struct is a pointer member, then yes, you'll need to mallocate it.  If it's a "normal" member, then no, it's already mallocated as part of its parent.

Comment: one job to one list_elem. So: Struct job contains a struct list_elem. I am trying to do something like: `j->elem = (struct list_elem *) malloc(sizeof(struct list_elem))` but I get an error saying `incompatible types when assigning struct list_elem` from `struct list_elem*`. Is it because `struct list_elem` has to be a pointer in `struct job` and not an actual struct?

Comment: Great! So would it differ if it a pointer member or a normal member? Or is it just safer to make it a pointer and just free it?

Comment: @Nayefc: If you don't need to dynamically allocate it, then make it a normal member.

Comment: That will in essence, create a "new" struct within the parent, each time a new parent is created. True?

Comment: @Nayefc: Hmm, it's difficult to answer that without having some code to talk about.  Perhaps you should create a new question on this topic.

Comment: I think that you want the code {j = malloc(sizeof(struct job));}, followed later by the code {free(j);}.  Because the list_elem is a member of the job, the one malloc() suffices to allocate storage for the entire job, including the list_elem.  But I suspect a possibility that all this isn't quite the answer you're looking for, because maybe you haven't yet formulated the *question* you're looking for.  Are you sure that you want one job that contains one list_elem?  (It is possible.  The Linux kernel code does such often.  But it is somewhat unusual.)

Comment: Rather than forking the conversation, I'll leave it in @OliCharlesworth's hands from this point.  Good luck.